# array of integer

Tags: iphone

please tell me that can we create an array of imteger in objective c
i am a new iphone programmer and i am creating an aray which can take an integer from a view (at 0th position)and pass that array to next view and then again put an integer to it (at 1st position) and so on....
please help
because it does not accept integer value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only store objects in `NSArray`s, not primitives (like `int`, `float`, `NSInteger`, etc.), which is probably what you're trying. Use `NSNumber` instead.

Comment: but if i use
NSNumber *myInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag];

[myarray addObject:myInt];
it show null on oth position of my array i have already declared my array no compilation problen is there......

Comment: You'll have to rephrase your question. I am having trouble understanding. If you are trying to add objects to an `NSArray` after initialization, that will not work, as it is not a *mutable* class. You will want to use `NSMutableArray` instead.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is add NSNumbers to the array.

```
[myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInteger]];
```

And to access the integer from the array

```
int myInteger = [[myArray objectAtIndex:myIndex] intValue];
```